# Which one of given set is connected...

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Which of the following are connected?

(*Notation:* $c(a, r) =\{(x, y) \in\mathbb R^2: (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2\}$)

1. $c(0,1) \cup c(0,2)$
2. $c(0,1) \cup c(1,3)$
3. $c(0,1) \cup c(1,1)$
4. $c(0,1) \cup c(2,1)$

Comment: Is $b$ supposed to be fixed, the same for each case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 and 4 is not connected. Just draw a picture and you will find it, and also a prove follows.

Comment: @ wisher why not 1 and 2...

Comment: @Prasanta have you try to graph those sets?

Comment: @ wisher...first one is circle with radius 2 ...so it should be connected...

Comment: @Prasanta this is correct

Comment: @ wisher...please tell me how can we show 3 and 4 are not connected without drawing the graph...

Comment: @Prasanta what if you assume they connected? A point in the intersection of two (closed) balls right? Then what happens to this point?